# Let $ \ V \ $ be a vector space and suppose that $ \{U_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ are subspaces of $ \ V \ $

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $ \ V \ $ be a vector space and suppose that $ \{U_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ are subspaces of $ \ V \ $ . Then prove that , if for every $\ k,\ m\ \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists an $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ $ such that $ \ U_{k} \cup U_{m} \subseteq U_{n} $ **then**  $ \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $  is a subspace of $ \ V \ $. $$ $$ I know that union of two subspaces is a subspace iff one is contained in another. I want to use this property **but  I am not sure how to prove the result ?**  Any help is appreciating .

Comment: what is $k$ in you statement?

Comment: Did you ever hear of *direct limits*?

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be that for every $m, n \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ U_{m} \cup U_{m} \subseteq U_{m}$?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $0\in   \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $

If $x\in   \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $

Then $x\in U_p$ for some $p\in \mathbb{N}$, so $\alpha x\in U_p$ which implies  $\alpha x \in \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $.

Also if $x,y\in  \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $, then $x\in U_k$ and $y\in U_m$ for some natural numbers $k,m$ hence they belong to a subspace $U_n$ for some integer $n$ (By the conditions given in the question,) which implies $x+y \in U_n$, so  $ x+y \in \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $.

Hence  $ \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n} \ $ is clearly a subspace of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

You meant to say for every k and m there is an n . Look if x is in U_k and if y is in U_m  you are assuming there is n so that both x and y are in U_n (a subspace ) so ... This should do it for you ,